# Unable to Create S3 Bucket(in specific Region) using AWS Python Boto3

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I am trying to create bucket using aws python boto 3.

Here is my code:-

```py
import boto3
response = S3_CLIENT.create_bucket(
  Bucket='symbols3arg',
  CreateBucketConfiguration={'LocationConstraint': 'eu-west-1'}
)
print(response)
```

I am getting below error:-

> botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (IllegalLocationConstraintException) when calling the CreateBucket operation: The unspecified location constraint is incompatible for the region specific endpoint this request was sent to.

Comment: How did you initiate your S3 client ? The reason is that the client is initated in a different region than 'eu-west-1'

Comment: See https://russell.ballestrini.net/setting-region-programmatically-in-boto3/

Comment: @WalidK I didn't provide the region for S3 client.

Comment: check your credentials config file ~/.aws/config
 and AWS_DEFAULT_REGION environment variable

Answer (score 4):

This happens you configured a different region during `aws configure` in specifying a different region in s3 client object initiation.

Suppose my AWS config look like

```
$ aws configure
AWS Access Key ID [None]: AKIAIOSFODEXAMPLE
AWS Secret Access Key [None]: wJalrXUtnFEMI/K7MDENG/bPxRfiCYEXAMPLEKEY
Default region name [None]: us-west-2
Default output format [None]: json
```

and my python script for creating bucket

```
import logging
import boto3
from botocore.exceptions import ClientError


def create_bucket(bucket_name, region=None):
    # Create bucket
    try:
        if region is None:
            s3_client = boto3.client('s3')
            s3_client.create_bucket(Bucket=bucket_name)
        else:
            s3_client = boto3.client('s3')
            location = {'LocationConstraint': region}
            s3_client.create_bucket(Bucket=bucket_name,
                                    CreateBucketConfiguration=location)
    except ClientError as e:
        logging.error(e)
        return False
    return True

create_bucket("test-bucket-in-region","us-west-1")
```

This will throw the below error

```
 ERROR:root:An error occurred (IllegalLocationConstraintException) when calling the CreateBucket operation: The us-west-1 location constraint is incompatible for the region specific endpoint this request was sent to.
```

[image]
To solve this issue all you need to specify the region in s3 client object initiation. A working example in different region regardless of `aws configure`

```
import logging
import boto3
from botocore.exceptions import ClientError


def create_bucket(bucket_name, region=None):
    """Create an S3 bucket in a specified region

    If a region is not specified, the bucket is created in the S3 default
    region (us-east-1).

    :param bucket_name: Bucket to create
    :param region: String region to create bucket in, e.g., 'us-west-2'
    :return: True if bucket created, else False
    """

    # Create bucket
    try:
        if region is None:
            s3_client = boto3.client('s3')
            s3_client.create_bucket(Bucket=bucket_name)
        else:
            s3_client = boto3.client('s3', region_name=region)
            location = {'LocationConstraint': region}
            s3_client.create_bucket(Bucket=bucket_name,
                                    CreateBucketConfiguration=location)
    except ClientError as e:
        logging.error(e)
        return False
    return True

create_bucket("my-working-bucket","us-west-1")
```

[create-an-amazon-s3-bucket](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/s3-example-creating-buckets.html)

Answer (score 1):

Send the command to S3 in the same region:

```py
import boto3

s3_client = boto3.client('s3', region_name='eu-west-1')
response = s3_client.create_bucket(
  Bucket='symbols3arg',
  CreateBucketConfiguration={'LocationConstraint': 'eu-west-1'}
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following code:

```
import boto3

client = boto3.client('s3',region_name="aws_region_code")

response = client.create_bucket(
    Bucket='string'
)
```