# AWS presigned URLS location constraint is incompatible for the region specific endpoint this request was sent to

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, boto3

I am using a lambda to create a pre-signed URL to download files that land in an S3 bucket -
the code works and I get a URL but when trying to access it I get
`af-south-1 location constraint is incompatible for the region-specific endpoint this request was sent to.`
both the bucket and the lambda are in the same region
I'm at a loss as to what is actually happening any ideas or solutions would be greatly appreciated.

my code is below

````
import json
import boto3
import boto3.session


def lambda_handler(event, context):
    session = boto3.session.Session(region_name='af-south-1')
    s3 = session.client('s3')
    for record in event['Records']:
        bucket = record['s3']['bucket']['name']
        key = record['s3']['object']['key']

    url = s3.generate_presigned_url(ClientMethod='get_object',
                                    Params={'Bucket': bucket,
                                    'Key': key}, ExpiresIn = 400)
    print (url)```
````

Comment: How do you use the url? Maybe you try to use it with s3 endpoint in different region then `af-south-1`?

Answer (score 4):

Set an `endpoint_url=https://s3.af-south-1.amazonaws.com` while generating the `s3_client`

```
s3_client = session.client('s3', 
                           region_name='af-south-1',
                           endpoint_url='https://s3.af-south-1.amazonaws.com')
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try using the `boto3` **client** directly rather than via the **session**, and generate the pre-signed url :

```
import boto3
import requests

# Get the service client.
s3 = boto3.client('s3',region_name='af-south-1')

# Generate the URL to get 'key-name' from 'bucket-name'
url = s3.generate_presigned_url(
    ClientMethod='get_object',
    Params={
        'Bucket': 'bucket-name',
        'Key': 'key-name'
    }
)
```

You could also have a look at these [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57146311/unable-to-create-s3-bucketin-specific-region-using-aws-python-boto3) & [2](https://github.com/boto/boto3/issues/2098), which resembles the same issue.

Comment: Thanks - I did initially use the boto3 client directly and had the same issue.
I spoke someone I know who works at AWS  he mentioned it may be an oddity with the new DCs and different policies. The same code deployed to Dublin worked as expected.

Comment: So, the only way out is to create the bucket on a different region?